# Remove Old Files/folders In Linux

Tags: bash

```
./myapp-maven-snapshots 
--25 Mar 2009      archetype-catalog.xml 
./myapp-maven-snapshots/com/org/teamcity/notifier/
        maven-metadata.xml
        maven-metadata.xml.md5
        maven-metadata.xml.sha1
        ./1.1.1-SNAPSHOT
                mynotifier-1.1.1-20160523.113654-1.pom
                mynotifier-1.1.1-20160523.113654-1.pom.sha1
                mynotifier-1.1.1-20160523.113654-1.pom.md5
                mynotifier-1.1.1-20160523.113654-1.jar
                mynotifier-1.1.1-20160523.113654-1.jar.md5
                maven-metadata.xml
                maven-metadata.xml.sha1
                maven-metadata.xml.md5
        ./1.1.2-SNAPSHOT
                mynotifier-1.1.2-20170523.113654-1.pom
                mynotifier-1.1.2-20170523.113654-1.pom.sha1
                mynotifier-1.1.2-20170523.113654-1.pom.md5
                mynotifier-1.1.2-20170523.113654-1.jar
                mynotifier-1.1.2-20170523.113654-1.jar.md5
                maven-metadata.xml
                maven-metadata.xml.sha1
                maven-metadata.xml.md5
        ./1.1.3-SNAPSHOT
                mynotifier-1.1.3-20180323.113654-1.pom
                mynotifier-1.1.3-20180323.113654-1.pom.sha1
                mynotifier-1.1.3-20180323.113654-1.pom.md5
                mynotifier-1.1.3-20180323.113654-1.jar
                mynotifier-1.1.3-20180323.113654-1.jar.md5
                maven-metadata.xml
                maven-metadata.xml.sha1
                maven-metadata.xml.md5
```

I have an artifact Repository on Linux server. Above is the folder structure for one of the maven snapshot repository. I want to delete old artifacts, lets say more than 1 year old.
I run below find+remove command for the same

```
find ./*maven*snapshots -type f -mtime +365 -printf "%h\0" | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

However if we notice that the file *archetype-catalog.xml* is quite old hence the -printf %h displays ./myapp-maven-snapshots as one of the directory to be removed, hence this deletes everything including files/folders which are not 1 year old.

How can I tweak this command or some new suggestions such that it works as desired.
Also note that since  we have multiple files inside the -SNAPSHOT directory each entry displays the same parent folder as intended to be deleted.

e.g. the output of the partial command is

```
find ./*maven*snapshots -type f -mtime +365 -printf "%h\0" | xargs -0

./myapp-maven-snapshots
 ./myapp-maven-snapshots/com/org/teamcity/notifier/1.1.1-SNAPSHOT
 ./myapp-maven-snapshots/com/org/teamcity/notifier/1.1.1-SNAPSHOT 
 ./myapp-maven-snapshots/com/org/teamcity/notifier/1.1.1-SNAPSHOT
 ./myapp-maven-snapshots/com/org/teamcity/notifier/1.1.1-SNAPSHOT
 ./myapp-maven-snapshots/com/org/teamcity/notifier/1.1.1-SNAPSHOT
 ./myapp-maven-snapshots/com/org/teamcity/notifier/1.1.1-SNAPSHOT
 ./myapp-maven-snapshots/com/org/teamcity/notifier/1.1.2-SNAPSHOT
 ./myapp-maven-snapshots/com/org/teamcity/notifier/1.1.2-SNAPSHOT 
 ./myapp-maven-snapshots/com/org/teamcity/notifier/1.1.2-SNAPSHOT
 ./myapp-maven-snapshots/com/org/teamcity/notifier/1.1.2-SNAPSHOT
 ./myapp-maven-snapshots/com/org/teamcity/notifier/1.1.2-SNAPSHOT
 ./myapp-maven-snapshots/com/org/teamcity/notifier/1.1.2-SNAPSHOT
```

Pain Points: 
There are multiple snapshot directories which needs to be filtered and deleted, 
The folder structure is not same for all repo
All repo does not have -SNAPSHOTS for their artifacts

Comment: this `-mtime +365` will NOT match *files/folders which are not 1 year old*

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest; -mtime +365, this will filter files which are more than 1 year old, however due to the structure of the directory and the find command that was used, it reads the folder /myapp-maven-snapshots as `should be deleted`; hence the folder ./1.1.3-SNAPSHOT also gets removed although its NOT one year old however a child folder under ./myapp-maven-snapshots

Comment: Why do you delete not only the old files/directories but also their parent directories? Try `-print0` instead of `-printf '%h\n'`

Comment: @Socowi, I need to delete the parent directories too, in the above example, consider that we delete all the .jar, pom and xml files (using the -print0 option) however we will be left over with empty directories, 1.1.1-SNAPSHOT, 1.1.2-SNAPSHOT, which I do not need.We have have many snapshot artifacts which run into 100's hence although the files are deleted the empty -SNAPSHOT directory gives a wrong impression that the artifacts still remains when in actual case it is removed; hence need to remove old artifact FILES and its parent directory.

Comment: When all files in the directory are older than one year, shouldn't the directory also be older than one year and be automatically deleted? Of course, there could still be the problem of some files being older than one year and some newer -- that would partially delete a snapshot. What is your expected behavior in that case?

Comment: Yes, if all files are older than one year then the folder too will be of the same age hence both of these should be deleted. In the second scenario, only the older files must be deleted, retaining the newer files and the the snapshot directory intact